# Изменить imageView в Listview после выполнения onItemClickListener()

Tags: listview, imageview

Всем привет!! Подскажите плз непонимаю что за магия происходит!!! Идея такая: у меня в ListView есть ImageView который должен меняться после нажатия пользователем на определенную строку ListView. Я к ListView вешаю слушателя onItemClickListener() и в нем реализую смену картинки. После нажатия картинка таки меняется но почему-то не только в той строке которую нажали, а во всем списке через каждые шесть строк!!! Не понимаю ка это происходит в чем проблемма ведь код элементарный!!!

```
 listViewMainActivity.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_for_change);//////
            iconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_folder_yellou_24dp);/////////////// тут проблема 

            currentSongIndex = position;

            playSong(currentSongIndex);

            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            btnPrevious.setEnabled(true);

            searchBox.clearFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` при пролистывании не удаляет старых детей и создаёт новых, а переиспользует их. Когда ребенок листа уйдет за границу экрана, например вверх, он не будет удален. При дальнейшем пролистывании он будет помещен в самый низ этого листа, но все свое внутреннее состояние при таких перемещениях ребенок сохраняет. Видимо у вас на экран помещается как раз 6 элементов. И если поменять картинку у первого элемента и пролистнуть вверх, то первый элемент, после того, как скроется за границей экрана, будет помещен в низ листа. И картинка будет отображаться как раз та, что и была на момент скрытия - то есть измененная.

Для того, чтобы этого избежать нужно в адаптере листа в методе `getView` вручную устанавливать необходимую для данной позиции картинку.

Все это верно в предположении, что как раз в адаптере в методе `getView` вы используете `convertView`, иначе желательно показать весь код.

Comment: Пасибо за ответ и внимание, я уже понял, что нужно именно в адаптере каждому елементу задавать картинку а не присваивать "полю" ViewImage в xml-ке. буду думать. Ведь теперь после изменения картинки нужно запомнить позицию в ArrayList где было изменение и при повторном нажатии на это же поле вновь менять картинку на прежнюю.